# The order of the result $x^2 \left(b-\frac{a}{2}\right)+(a-2) x^3+\left(2-\frac{b}{2}\right) x+4 x^4-1$

Tags: output-formatting, polynomials

Can you explain me a little how *Mathematica* sort this result, and how to sort in descending powers of $x$

```
(x - 1/2) (4 x^3 + a x^2 + b x + 2) // Expand // Collect[#, x] &
```

$$\begin{align*}x^2 \left(b-\frac{a}{2}\right)+(a-2) x^3+\left(2-\frac{b}{2}\right) x+4 x^4-1\end{align*}$$

how to get the following order

$$\begin{align*}4x^4+(a-2)x^3+\left(b-\frac{a}{2}\right) x^2+\left(2-\frac{b}{2}\right)x-1\end{align*}$$

Comment: @Nasser I'm doing exploring manipulation, and after `Expand`, then I realized that I need `Collect`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is undocumented but I saw it once:

```
(x - 1/2) (4 x^3 + a x^2 + b x + 2) // Expand // Collect[#, x] & // 
           PolynomialForm[#, TraditionalOrder -> True] &
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw something similar in MathWorld of Eric's Notebook.

Answer (score 2):

fyi http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PolynomialOrderings.html  has alot of information relating to this:

```
MonomialList[Collect[ Expand[(x - 1/2) (4 x^3 + a x^2 + b x + 2)], x], Reverse[{x}]]

(* {4 x^4, (-2 + a) x^3, (-(a/2) + b) x^2, (2 - b/2) x, -1} *)
```